# Adding subview to UICollectionView - disables scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to add a subview to a UICollectionView in order to make a left panel that scrolls with the collectionview.

Using

```
[self.collectionView addSubview:myView]
```

all touches become disabled and I can no longer scroll the view. I've read that adding a subview to a collectionView like this is bad practice.. is this true? Why does it disable touches from reaching the collectionView event when

```
userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

I'm trying to do this: [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EbU8.jpg) by grabbing the frame position of the first cell in each section, and adding a dot with to myView with the same y value.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are u using UICollectionViewController?

Comment: @muku no, custom view controller.

Comment: `[self.view insertSubview:myView aboveSubview:self.collectionView ]`,Have u tried this

Comment: While that does restore the ability to scroll, the view does not scroll with the collectionview

Answer (score 1):

Adding subviews using the `addSubview:` method to a `UICollectionView` is very bad practice. It can cause a lot of different problems in the normal behaviour of the CollectionView. It can obstruct the views underneath it, capture the touch events, preventing them from reaching the actual scrollView inside the CollectionView, etc. The subviews added using this method will also not scroll as the other elements in the CollectionView do.

The correct way to do what you want is to implement a new type of `UICollectionViewCell` for the dots, and compute their locations in the `prepareForLayout` and `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`  methods. Basically you'll have either one or two cells in each row. Which ones will have two rows will be determined by you in the methods I've mentioned.

In fact, Apple's docs have a perfect example that's even more complex than what you're trying you achieve. You should check it out from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH8-SW6).

Answer (score -1):

May I know the purpose of that scroll view ? Because, if you're looking for a subview that displays only a label or image etc., You can use custom collectionview cell instead if I am not wrong... Hope it helps :) :)